# Tkinter does not show second drop down list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning Tkinter basics and in one of tutorials we create drop down menus. In video everything works fine, but in my program it does not show second drop down menu, called "Edit" (picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fND3W.png)).

Code is almost identical. There are no errors in console. Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def doNothing():
    print('I am useless')

def doNothing2():
    print('I am useless too')

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root) #creates menu for window
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
# Creating dropdown menus is called cascading.
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label='New File', command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label='New Project', command=doNothing2)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=doNothing)

EditMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
EditMenu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=EditMenu)
EditMenu.add_command(label='Undo', command=doNothing)
EditMenu.add_command(label='Redo', command=doNothing2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OS: windows 10 pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `.add_cascade()` to make the `EditMenu` a submenu of *itself*, not of the top-level menu.  Take a closer look at how the file menu was added.

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `EditMenu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=EditMenu)`
you should do: `menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=EditMenu)` so that it adds the EditMenu to the parent menu instead of itself.